# How to merge a PR from command line using hub?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm using *git / hub* with *github* following a *gitflow* workflow in my project and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to avoid entering github to merge and close my pull requests.

The worflow I'm following at the time is this one.

```
git checkout -b my-feature-123 develop
git add .
git commit -m "my changes"
git push origin my-feature-123
hub pull-request -m "my changes" -b develop
#enter guthub and merge PR
#run deployment 
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop # everything up-to-date
```

So I want to replace the *#enter guthub and merge PR* part with a command line merging command, till now nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

It should be possible to merge the feature branch from the command line using git's merge command. First, you'll need to checkout the branch you are merging to which in this case is develop:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff my-feature-123
git push
```

The --no-ff is used to prevent a fast-forward merge which is the behavior you'd want for gitflow.

Comment: that's a good alternative. What I'm really looking for is to merge the pull-request

Comment: Actually this seems to do the trick, a few more testings before green tick

Comment: the only modification I'd do is git push origin develop at the last command

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible via a `hub` command dedicated for pull requests and performing merges.

However, it can be done using [hub-api](https://hub.github.com/hub-api.1.html) and [Pulls API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/#merging) using the following script ([source](https://github.com/mislav/hub-api-utils/blob/master/bin/hub-pr-merge)):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: hub-pr-merge <PR-NUMBER>
#
# Cause a pull request to be merged into its respective base branch.
#
# Author: Oliver Joseph Ash

# If a script errors, force the script to fail immediately.
set -e

ID=$1
shift 1

# https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button
hub api -XPUT "repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/$ID/merge" "$@"
```